# SocketIO Communication with a Gateway Between the Client and a Service?

Tags: node.js, sockets, kubernetes, socket.io, microservices

### Gist

I have an application that runs on an microservice-based architecture (on Kubernetes). All the communication to/from outside the application happens through an **API Gateway**.

Which just means that requests from my frontend don't go directly to the services, but they have to go through the Gateway.

### Motive

Now I need to implement a feature that requires realtime communication between the frontend and an internal service. But since the internal service is not exposed to the outside, I need a way to "route" the realtime data through the Gateway.

All my services are running on Node.js, which is the reason I want to use [Socket.IO](https://socket.io/) to implement the realtime communication.

[image: architecture]

### Issue

**But how to implement the purple double arrow from the sketch?**

So usually the frontend client would connect to the server where Socket.IO is running. But in my case this server (the realtime feature server) is not accessible from the client (and never should be), which means that the client has to connect to the Gateway. Thus the Gateway needs to implement some mechanism to route all incoming messages to the realtime service and vice verca.

### Ideas

(1) Have a second HTTP server listening for events on the Gateway and emit those event to the realtime server. In the other direction, the realtime server will emit events to the Gateway, which wiil then emit them to the frontend. I think this approach will definitely work, but it seems redundant to emit everything twice. And it would definitely hurt performance?

(2) Use a Socket.IO Adapter to "[pass event between nodes](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-website/blob/master/source/docs/using-multiple-nodes.md#passing-events-between-nodes)", which seems as the right way to go because it is used to "pass messages between processes or computers". But I have problems getting started because of the lack of documentation / examples. I am also not using Redis (is it needed to use the adapter?)

(3) Use the [socket.io-emitter](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-emitter) package, which seems not like a good option since the last commit was from 3 years ago.

(4) Something else?

Comment: so You must use the API Gateway to redirect traffic? We have socket.io implemented in pour application but the service has deployed in a separate service (pod). Using `ingress-controller` k8s sends the `socket` traffic to the soccer service.

Comment: @GiorgioCerruti No I don't **have** to use the Gateway, but this is how I planned my application to work. So you would recommend just exposing my "internal service" via Ingress?

Comment: I did it using `nginx` as an ingress-controller. You can use haproxy as well if you prefer. You will have 2 services (deployment) 1 to manage HTTP(s) requests and 1 to manage socket requests. Using ingress you can expose path and redirect traffic to the right service e.g. every request wich hit `/socket` will be redirected to `socket-service` application.

Comment: ok that sounds like something wort trying, because I already use nginx Ingress. It would be awesome if you could post an answer showcasing how to implement it (Here is the ingress config I currently use: https://github.com/flolu/centsideas/blob/245e123c94a08f091c7ff59b9aa049d549eb474d/packages/kubernetes/ingress.yaml)

Answer (score 3):

Alright, basically I designed the application like this

***Ingress***

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: centsideas-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: 'true'
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: 'nginx'
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - centsideas.com
        - api.centsideas.com
      secretName: centsideas-tls
  rules:
    - host: api.centsideas.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /socker.io
            backend: 
             serviceName: socket-service
             servicePort: 8000
          -  path: /
             backend:
              serviceName: centsideas-gateway
              servicePort: 3000
    - host: centsideas.com
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: centsideas-client
              servicePort: 8080
```

***Service***

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
 name: socket-service
 annotations:
  service.beta.kubernetes.io/external-traffic: "OnlyLocal" 
 namespace: namespace
spec:
 sessionAffinity: ClientIP
 ports:
  - name: ws-port
    protocol: TCP
    port: 8000
 type: ClusterIP
 selector:
  service: ws-api
```

Then you create your deployment to deploy the ws-service. Like this, you can also activate k8s HPA (horizontal pod autoscaling) to scale up the socket.io service. 
You must change annotations and other options based on your k8s version (I think the annotation `service.beta.kubernetes.io/external-traffic: "OnlyLocal"` has been deprecated).

Comment: Ok nice! Just to clarify: for every internal service that requires web sockets I would add another `socket-service` and add it to the Ingress?

Comment: It depends. If you need to expose new services (new codebase) yes, you have to create new k8s services each microservice. Instead, if you need to scale up your socket.io application (create more instance of the same codebase), no you don't. A service is basically a LoadBalancer made by k8s using iptables, it will balance your request between instances deciding by its own which pod is not busy with requests/resources.

Comment: Makes sense, it depends on the use case :)
So I will wait a few days just in case I'll get some other answers. If not you'll get the bounty, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As the internal service is not exposed to the outside, I recommend using a tunnel. ngrok is a command for an instant and secure URL to your localhost server through any NAT or firewall.
If your server exposes the socket service through a certain port, using **ngrok** to create a reverse proxy to expose the world with which you can connect to your frontend application.
Using this command is very simple, here is an example of how to use it:

1. Register and download the ngrok file at the following address [Official site](https://ngrok.com/)
2. Just run the following instruction to make it work

   ./ngrok http 3000
3. To make it permanent you must create a service and use a file **ngrok.yml** for the best configuration.

Here is the official documentation [Here](https://ngrok.com/docs)

Comment: I was probably not precise enough in my answer. Your approach might work, but the internal service has to stay internal. No one from the outside should be able to talk to it with a direct connection